# como ejecutar compilado webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nginx, webpack

Si se genera un proyecto un proyecto con webpack para correrlo es forzoso correrlo bajo nginx??? o se puede ocupar apache, esto si es un desarrollo sin uso de framework como VUE, REACT o ANGULAR

Answer (score 0):

No es obligatorio usar Nginx, puedes usar cualquier servidor web siempre y cuando tenga capacidad para rescribir las URLs.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Te dejo como referencia esta URL de la documentación de Vue, donde te muestra distintas configuraciones de ejemplo que puedes usar como plantillas en tu servidor.

### Apache

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

### Nginx

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```